# ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\def \begin{

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[amsmath]
\begin{document}
\author{charisfilis}
\begin{equation}
\gr
1. Λύσε την διαφορική εξίσωση :
$$
 \frac{\partial^2y}{\partialx^2}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = {\partial s}{\partial t}
$$
\end{equation}
           Τέλος Σπιτεργασίας
\end{document}
```

I have problem to that portion of latex code that i can't find a way to debug it please help me if u can.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` instead of `\usepackage[amsmath]`. And remove the `$$...$$` pair from inside the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. And move the text outside the `\begin{equation}`, and add a space after `\partial` in `\partialx^2`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason nowadays to load `ucs` and to use `utf8x` (which have been long unmaintained).

If your default language is Greek, put the option last.

The `equation` environment should contain just math, the text goes outside it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

1. Λύσε την διαφορική εξίσωση:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = {\partial s}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
Τέλος Σπιτεργασίας

\end{document}
```

If your TeX distribution is not the most recent available, you may need to load

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Note that `[]` is for options, `{}` for the name of the package.

[image]